# Creating an object list immutable for beginner in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to create an object list, but when I define an object into a list, after I update the object, the list is also updated.

I have then realized that lists only refers to the memory where the object is allocated.

Can I do something simple, so that this object can be utilized and compared to an object that has been created using the same variable name?

For example, I want to compare the track Id from the previous object to the new one, without creating 2 different objects.

First, the object:

```
class SmartPhone
{
    private string TrackID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    private string Battery { get; set; }
    public uint ID { get; set; }

    // Static Variables
    static List<uint> usedIDs = new List<uint>();
    static uint qnty = 0;

    public SmartPhone(string _ProductName, string _PartNumber)
    {
        if (_PartNumber.Length == 14)
        {
            PartNumber = _PartNumber;
            ProductName = _ProductName;
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
```

The method:

```
    public void Associate(string TrackID, string BatteryPN)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PartNumber))
        {
            this.TrackID = TrackID;
            Battery = BatteryPN;

            if (!usedIDs.Contains(qnty))
            {
                qnty++;
                ID = qnty;
                usedIDs.Add(ID);
            }
        }
    }
```

And calling the method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmartPhone Test = new SmartPhone("30", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        List<SmartPhone> SmartUsed = new List<SmartPhone>();
        Test.Associate("TCID1201", "BT487878");
        SmartUsed.Add(Test);
        Test.Associate("TQX201201", "BX913748");
        SmartUsed.Add(Test);
    }
```

Comment: The only way to compare values on an object reference with values that were previously on the same object reference is to store a history of the values somewhere. The problem is you've described a proposed solution and a problem you are having, but instead you should try to explain what you are trying to do as this will help guide others to a solution for you. I suspect that you are asking an X/Y question here. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Adding to @Chaeleh's comment: What is wrong with creating a new object? You can use the same variable name for the new object if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am not a very experienced developer, so I'll try my best to explain.

Comment: Don't worry about experience levels, as long as you can explain what you want in plain English the more experienced people can guide you on the programming bit :)

Comment: I need to do association of a determined product and battery, but to do so, I need them to keep the same pattern. For example:
XXX-xxx-NNN -
XXX: constant values
xxx: variable values
nnn: incremental values.

And my ideia is to keep them in a list, so I can compare the previous object, to the newer, and see if they're keeping the same pattern for the values.

Comment: Ok, so let me just make sure I understand; the first added value needs to set the pattern and any later associations need to match the pattern? Is this pattern not pre-determined? Are you generating the numbers? Are the patterns part numbers or something like that? Going back a bit more - why do you need to ensure the patterns match, what's the use case for this code?

Comment: I need to make sure those numbers match, 'cause they will be later inserted into another application that check those IDs match, because they will be attributed to a responsible. If they are wrong, the person will receive a product that never existed.

Comment: There are 10 characters in the ID, 3 will be fixed, 3 will be variable, and 4 will be incremental, but they are all pre-determined (EX: XXXABC0001, XXXDEF0002, XXXABC0003).

Comment: I don't understand what the use of the usedIDs list is.. you can get the index of the item from the list either by looping or using indexof, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do. What does TrackID represent. If you tell us more about what you are trying to do as a whole we might be able to give better guidance. You've declared a class called `SmartPhone`, but what does it actually represent? What are you trying to do from a very general perspective?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) vs [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types). You might also want to read up on [equality comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons).

A way to make your life simpler is to make objects immutable and implement [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netcore-3.1) for your types. By doing this you remove most of the behavior difference between reference and value types. Using this pattern the Associate method should return a new Smartphone object with the specified Track and battery. This object that can be added to the list, and no existing object will be affected.

If you are concerned by the overhead of creating additional objects, don't be. Worry about the program being correct first, and only worry about performance if you have reasons to believe it is or will be a problem.

I would also recommend against using static fields, at least ones that are changed. This is a great way to make your code non-threadsafe and can introduce odd side effect that are difficult to understand.